# Java 11 module-info: how to register an annotation processor

Tags: java, java-11, annotation-processing, module-info

To register a service provider in a Java 11 the following "provides" module-info entry can be used:

```
module com.mycompany.mylib {

    provides ServiceInterface with ServiceImpl;

}
```

With annotation processors this doesn't seem to work, however. (The special thing with annotation processors is that it's the compiler which should pick up the implementation during compile time rather than the application during runtime.)

To test this out, I've created some [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)s on [GitHub](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test).

There are 2 modules:

- `java11-sample-annotation-processor`: provides the `@Foo` annotation and the `FooApplicationProcessor`
- `java11-sample-lib`: provides 2 sample classes, both using the `@Foo` annotation

**Expected output:** in the `java11-sample-lib` JAR there should be a `foo.txt` file

The version in the [master branch](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test) is the one **that works**:

- Java 11
- no `module-info` used
- annotation processor registration in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`

In the following versions the `foo.txt` file is not generated:

In the [registration-in-module-info branch](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test/tree/registration-in-module-info) I've changed the 2 libs to Java 11 modules with module-info.
The annotation processor is here registered in the module-info:

```
import com.github.puce77.java11annotationprocessortest.annotation.impl.FooApplicationProcessor;

module com.github.puce77.java11annotationprocessortest.annotation {
    exports com.github.puce77.java11annotationprocessortest.annotation;

    provides javax.annotation.processing.Processor with FooApplicationProcessor;

    requires java.compiler;
}
```

The [registration-in-module-info-moduleAndPkg branch](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test/tree/registration-in-module-info-moduleAndPkg) is [a slight variation](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test/compare/registration-in-module-info...registration-in-module-info-moduleAndPkg), where I specified the target module and target package (hardcoded) rather than the root package.

In the [registration-meta-inf branch](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test/tree/registration-meta-inf) still both have a module-info but the annotation processor is registered in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` rather than in the module-info (in case the compiler can not work with provides statements in the module-info!?)

In the [only-one-module branch](https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test/tree/only-one-module) I've removed the module-info from the `java11-sample-annotation-processor` again. The annotation processor is registered in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`.

So my question: how can I configure an annotation processor when working with Java 11 modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It used to be that annotation processors were automatically detected when placed on the class-path during compilation. You can see this from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html) of `javac`:

> `--class-path` *path*, `-classpath` *path*, or `-cp` *path*
>
> Specifies where to find user class files **and annotation processors** *[emphasis added]*. This class path overrides the user class path in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.
>
> - If `--class-path`, `-classpath`, or `-cp` are not specified, then the user class path is the value of the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, if that is set, or else the current directory.
> - If not compiling code for modules, if the `--source-path` or `-sourcepath` option is not specified, then the user class path is also searched for source files.
> - **If the `-processorpath` option is not specified, then the class path is also searched for annotation processors** *[emphasis added]*.
>
> *[...]*
>
> `--processor-path` *path* or `-processorpath` *path*
>
> Specifies where to find annotation processors. **If this option is not used, then the class path is searched for processors** *[emphasis added]*.

And this is still the case as long as you're using the class-path. This is not the case, however, when using the module-path. For modular annotation processors to be detected you have to explicitly point to them with another option:

> `--module-path` *path* or `-p` *path*
>
> Specifies where to find application modules.
>
> *[...]*
>
> `--processor-module-path` *path*
>
> Specifies the module path used for finding annotation processors.

No mention of the module-path being used to automatically detect annotation processors.

Comment: This is realy strange as this makes annotation processing much more inconvenient.

Comment: So I ended up with the following solution: https://github.com/puce77/java11-annotation-processor-test/tree/solution

- register annotation processor both ways: module-info and META-INF, to support module path and classpath
- in modules: specify annotationProcessorPaths in the compiler plugin
- in non-modules: works out-of-the-box

Comment: @Puce thanks for sharing this! nice trick with `proc:none` for the processor module!